# How to use the equations for electrostatic work?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential-energy, voltage

I was reading Griffith's Introduction to Electrodynamics (3rd ed.) when I stumbled upon two equations. In electrostatics, the work required to move a charge $q$ between two points with different potentials can be written as

$W=q[V_{f}-V_{i}]$

On the other hand, the work required to assemble a charge distribution can be written as

$W={\varepsilon_{0}\over2}\int_{space}E^{2}d^{3}r$

Now say there is a problem such that I need to know the work required to move a plate of conductor closer to another plate of opposite charge, which equation to use?

Or more generally, in what case can I use each equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, you are not needing work to build up the charge distributions, only to move the plates, aka building up a distribution 1, in the presence of potential 2

$\int V_{2}(r') \rho_{1}(r')d^3r'$

This is building up the distribution $\rho_{1}$ from infinity

I believe to find the amount of work required to move it from a to b  would be to find the same integral where distribution $\rho_{1}$ is in the 2 locations, and subtract them.

If your safely ignoring fringe fields, you can find the difference between the field energy of the capacitor using capacitor equations and the difference is the work required.

Edit: in order to relate this to the original field energy equation.-
Look at my answer here, if you look at the energy of adistribution, where there are 2 distinct E fields produced by either plates you can identify the components

[Why does this integral calculating the electrostatic energy converge?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/681308/why-does-this-integral-calculating-the-electrostatic-energy-converge/681333#681333)